# Background image from file not working

Tags: css, background-image

It works when I do a URL from the internet, but not from a local file path. My directory of folders go

Website (folder with everything) --> images --> album --> tyler.jpg

so something with my link is messed up but I have tried everything I can think of.

```
.nav {
background: #ddd;
padding: 20px;
margin: 0;
}

.nav a {
padding: 10px;
}

.grid { 
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: 350px;
grid-gap: 1em;
margin: 30px 100px 30px 100px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.grid > * {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-color: grey;
}


.f1 {
grid-column: 1/3;
grid-row: 1/3;
background-image: url('Images/album/tyler.jpg');
color: #fff;
```

}

Comment: Uppercase "Images" vs. lowercase "images," maybe?

Comment: "Website (folder with everything)" Does "everything" include this CSS file?

Answer (score 1):

you should use a relative path starting with "/"

```
background-image: url('/images/album/tyler.jpg');
```

otherwise it will just append the path to the current url

Comment: I tried that, did not work. When I go to my html and add <img src="'/images/album/tyler.jpg'"> the link works and the picture shows up but it is not working in css

Comment: it also maybe your code contains syntax errors that cause this not normal behaviour. you can use the developer tools of the browser to see if the ressource couldnt be loaded and why